# Running all custom tools in separate tool script in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-toolbox

I created a toolbox with a bunch of scripts for ArcGIS Pro. I created a separate tool, `RunAll`, that runs all the tools within that toolbox. It runs at a good speed when I just run it as a python script, but is very slow in ArcGIS pro as a tool. Any tips/suggestions for a tool to run all tools in toolbox?
Example code for stand alone script:

```py
import arcpy
import os
arcpy.ImportToolbox(pyt_path, "myToolbox")
# get parameters
gdb_path = r"C:\Path\To\GDB.gdb"

# Run all tools
print(dir(arcpy.myToolbox))
for t in dir(arcpy.myToolbox):
    if t.startswith("_"):
        continue
    arcpy.AddMessage("Running {}".format(t))
    try:
        tool = getattr(arcpy.myToolbox,t)
        tool(gdb_path)
    except Exception as e:
        arcpy.AddError("{} failed...".format(t))
        arcpy.AddError(e)
        arcpy.AddError("-------------")
```

Example code below for `RunAll` tool to run the above script within ArcGIS Pro:

```py
import arcpy
from arcpy import Parameter
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
import os


class RunAll(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.label = "Run all"
        self.description = """Runs all Tools"""
        self.canRunInBackground = True

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        """Define parameter definitions"""
        input_gdb = Parameter(
            displayName='Input geodatabase',
            name='input_gdb',
            datatype='DEWorkspace',
            parameterType='Required',
            direction='Input')

        input_gdb.filter.list = ['Local Database']
        return [input_gdb]

    def isLicensed(self):
        """Set whether tool is licensed to execute."""
        return True

    def updateParameters(self, parameters):
        """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
        validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
        has been changed."""
        return

    def updateMessages(self, parameters):
        """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
        parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
        return

    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        """The source code of the tool."""
        pyt_path = r"C:\Path\to\custom\toolbox.pyt"
        arcpy.ImportToolbox(pyt_path, "myToolbox")
        # get parameters
        gdb_path = str(parameters[0].value)

        # Run all tools
        print(dir(arcpy.myToolbox))
        for t in dir(arcpy.myToolbox):
            if t.startswith("_"):
                continue
            arcpy.AddMessage("Running {}".format(t))
            try:
                tool = getattr(arcpy.myToolbox,t)
                tool(gdb_path)
            except Exception as e:
                arcpy.AddError("{} failed...".format(t))
                arcpy.AddError(e)
                arcpy.AddError("-------------")
                    
        return

    def postExecute(self, parameters):
        """This method takes place after outputs are processed and
        added to the display."""
        return
```